# Types for cardStyleInterpolator props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using this in my navigation stack:

```
  <NavigationStack.Screen
                    name="UserMenu"
                    component={UserMenu}
                    options={{
                      headerShown: false,
                      cardStyleInterpolator: forSlideFromLeft,
                    }}
                  />
```

```
const forSlideFromLeft = (props) => {
  const { current, layouts } = props;
  console.log('PROPS FROM USER MENU', current)
  console.log('PROPS FROM USER MENU2', layouts)
  const translateX = current.progress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-layouts.screen.width, 0],
  });
  if (props.index === 2) {
    return {
      cardStyle: {
        transform: [{ translateX }],
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};
```

but I get an error on `props` that `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.` What could be it's type. If I `infer from usage`in VS Code, I get this:

```
(props: { index?: any; current?: any; layouts?: any; })
```

But I don't want to use `any`types. If I print the `current`and `layout` values on the console, I get something like this:

current:

```
{progress: AnimatedInterpolation}
progress: AnimatedInterpolation {_listeners: {…}, _children: Array(0), _parent: AnimatedValue, _config: {…}, _interpolation: ƒ, …}
__proto__: Object
```

layout:

```
{screen: {…}}
screen: {width: 411.4285583496094, height: 707.4285888671875}
__proto__: Object
```

How can I fix this? What would be the suitable type to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can import `StackCardInterpolationProps` type from `react-navigation`

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/stack/src/types.tsx

Answer (score 0):

### In React Navigation 6

Check out the [type definition for `StackCardStyleInterpolator`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/838842e85fffd56a3a64a1f4e969318998217c7a/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L439-L441) in `@react-navigation`. This should work for animating screens in a Stack.

You can implement your `forSlideFromLeft` method like this:

```js
import {
  StackCardInterpolationProps,
  StackCardInterpolatedStyle,
} from "@react-navigation/stack";

const forSlideFromLeft = (
 { current, layouts, index }: StackCardInterpolationProps
): StackCardInterpolatedStyle => {
  const translateX = current.progress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-layouts.screen.width, 0],
  });
  if (index === 2) {
    return {
      cardStyle: {
        transform: [{ translateX }],
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};
```

There is also a [`StackHeaderStyleInterpolator`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/838842e85fffd56a3a64a1f4e969318998217c7a/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L509-L511) for animating headers.